# JavaScript modify CSS for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function tied to an anchor and on click, it modifies the display of a div from display none to block.

In that div i have another anchor which i want to use to hide the parent div.

See mock-up below:

```
<a href="#" onclick = "showText(); return false;" id="BtNews">Click</a>
```

This modifies the AllSources div display to block:

```
  <div id="EssentialSourcesTab"></div>
    <div id="AllSourcesTab">
 <a href="#" class="inline_link AllSourcesLink" id="showBottom"  onclick = "hideText(); return false;">
    </div>
```

I managed to get the first function to work, that modifies the CSS for the AllSourcesTab to display block and hides the EssentialSourcesTab, however, I cannot get the other anchor(showBottom) to work. Basically, I want to use to hide the AllSourcesTab and display the EssentialSourcesTab

```
 function showText() {
        document.getElementById("AllSourcesTab").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("EssentialSourcesTab").style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("BtNews").click = showText;
 function hideText() {
            document.getElementById("AllSourcesTab").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("EssentialSourcesTab").style.display = "block";
        }
        document.getElementById("showBottom").click = hideText;
```

Comment: try this ->  `document.getElementById("showBottom").click = hideText();`

Comment: Why are you calling the function twice? Once in the HTML and once in the JS itself.

Comment: Agreed, you have two `onclick` bindings. Besides, why the jQuery tag?